# How to mix static and dynamic tables in a single view

Tags: ios, uitableview

What is the approach taken to incorporate table view with dynamic content as well as static table cells, like the following views (Any sample code is appreciated but not necessary). For the sake of learning, I would like to hear how you would go about constructing each of the following screens:

[image]
[image]

Comment: it looks like group table , create two sections one for static and one for dynamic

Comment: @MikeAlter Mixing static and dynamic is not that straightforward afaik. You can only either select dynamic prototypes or static cells at the table view level. Perhaps the way to go is to create a few dynamic cells for the static content, and arrange them at runtime per section. But I'd like to see what other ideas are out there. Thinking about combining container views with various table view configurations.

Comment: Just use a pure dynamic table. What's the problem? I don't see what that table structure even has to do with static or dynamic. It's just a table.

Answer (score 0):

As far as possible, you shouldn't use static cells and dynamic cells together. It's a bad practice. This is because, when you use static cells, the dataSource for the tableView is set to be static, and cannot change at all.

But, there is a hack to this. And, you can use both static and dynamic cells together. But, you have to be really careful at doing this, otherwise your app can crash.

ToDo List:

**1. Override the
    cellForRowAtIndexPath method.**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  // For static section i.e. 0 index 
  if indexPath.section == 0 {
    // This returns the static cells
    return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
  } else {
    // This gives your dynamic cell
    let cell = myDynamicCell()
    return myDynamicCell
  }
}
```

Here, the myDynamicCell() method is your own method to create your dynamic cells. *You cannot use prototype cell at this point, because you chose static cells already. So, you have to create the cells through code.*

**Note:**

Keep in mind you are messing with the static dataSource. If any errors come at this point, it is your own responsibility as Apple states.

Also, this process is really dangerous, try to use dynamic cells and then set the first section dynamically to static. And, rest would be easy. This is the best approach to take. I would recommend this approach, but above approach would still work for this time, at least at the time of creating new cells.

Comment: Thanks @Suman, Can you share how you'd approach each of the shared screenshots? Fyi, In the first screenshot, the section in the middle labelled "Similar to you" is rendered asynchronously with a delay, showing a loading mask before data is made available. Which approach would make that possible? Also, would including container views of tableviewcontrollers in vertical stack be a viable solution?

Comment: The best approach as far as I know is to use dynamic cells only, sir. While I have read on about using static cells for the similar purpose in a book and implemented it, it is quite cumbersome and is not appropriate. 

Even the tutor/writer recommends to use it cautiously. I can only refer you to the book, friend. But, do not have rights to share all the code here. "iOS Apprentice Tutorial 2: Checklists" Book

https://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-apprentice